# Closable List Items by jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am new to jQuery..I wish to create a ul list (inline) which will have an close mark X besides every list item which when clicked, should delete that list item(or close/hide it)...

For Eg: I want the same effect which appears in when adding tags to a question here on stackoverflow.. We can delete the selected Tag by clickin X besides every tag

Thanks for your Help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example I've just made: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDgSX/1/.

Theres many ways to skin this cat but I'd probably do it like this, create a basic list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

Then, using the jquery .append() function, add a link on to the end of each of the list items like so:

```
$('ul li').append(' <span>[<a href="#">X</a>]</span>');
```

This is so that people who don't have javascript won't be able to click on a link that effectively will do nothing for them.

Then all you essentially need to do is create a click event for the "X" link, then remove the li element from the DOM.

```
$('ul span a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

It's a lot to get your head around at first but an excellent way to learn in more detail what these functions (and more) do is by reading the [jquery](http://jquery.com) docs.

Comment: I like the answer but I don't like what you have done in the fiddle of hiding the X until you mouseover. Bad usability in my opinion. :) (and yes, I know its not relevant to the correctness of the answer - its just an aside)

Comment: both the answers were good.. But i think i would go with mdk :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/s8rzu/1/